# How can I disable the error (prettier/prettier) on eslint?

Tags: javascript, react-native, atom-editor, eslint, eslintrc

While coding, I was not using eslint. Now I installed it and it has flooded my editor with prettier/prettier errors, which by no way seem like they make my code prettier. I am looking to find a way to solve this.

prettierrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: true,
  jsxBracketSameLine: false,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
};
```

eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
};
```

And finally, some example code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Picker} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {employeeUpdate} from '../actions';
import {CardSection,  Input} from './common';

class EmployeeForm extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
      <CardSection>
        <Input
          label="Name"
          placeholder="Marco"
          value={this.props.name}
          onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({prop: 'name', value})}
        />
      </CardSection>

      <CardSection>
        <Input
          label="Phone"
          placeholder="555-5555"
          value={this.props.phone}
          onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({prop: 'phone', value })}
        />
      </CardSection>

      <CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Shift</Text>
        <Picker
        style={{flex: 1}}
        selectedValue={this.props.shift}
        onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({prop: 'shift', value})}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday"/>
          <Picker.Item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday"/>
          <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday"/>
          <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday"/>
          <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday"/>
          <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="Sunday"/>
        </Picker>
      </CardSection>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am simply trying to remove the error since it is annoying to have thousands of red dots looking to make my code "prettier", which is not achieving.

Comment: https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html#turn-off-eslint-s-formatting-rules

Answer (score 212):

Instead of disabling linting for the file, you can instead disable prettier within the **eslintrc.js config file**:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 0,
  },
};
```

Comment: You saved me hours of searching/config. IntelliJ IDEA wasn't fixing ESLint errors due to this. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to just stop errors in compile time?

Comment: For my react-native project, this disables prettier indeed but not eslint yellow warnings

Comment: I can confirm this still works correctly with RN 0.66, so you may be seeing a different warning, or one come from another module. What rule is eslint returning warnings for?

Comment: This just saved me hours of hair pulling. I swear, excessive linting is going to turn me bald someday.

Comment: Glad to help! I really don't understand why they felt the need to make this default in the community package, when so many prefer not to use it.

Comment: Thirded! Already spent hours pulling hair and this comment finally saved the day! @DBrown

Comment: @Bryan did you get the solution? I don't like to add *Semi-colons* at the end of each line, but VS Code keeps highlighting these lines with yellow warnings.

Comment: @MuhammadTahirAli In VSCode's Problem area it should tell you which eslint rule is causing the warning, and more than likely it's coming from the default semicolon rule. Just set "semicolon": [0, "never"] in your eslintrc rules.

Comment: Is there a way to set this property globally?  It seems that I would have to do it for each project.

Comment: @Eric yes, you could use a global eslint config for this rule.

Comment: can I disable some specific prettier rules as well from .eslintrc.json? Ex I just want to turn off trailing comma prettier rule @DBrown

Comment: @Akshay I still don't think you can. You can find out more from the post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76152109/4488503

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of conflicting rules when using both - prettier and eslint there is a `eslint-config-prettier` package.

Run `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier` to install and then in `eslintrc.js` (or wherever you have the eslint rules defined) add:

```
{
  "extends": [
    ...,
    "@react-native-community",
    "prettier"
  ]
}
```

Now eslint should respect prettier rules. [Here is a link to GH repo](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier).

Comment: I already had both packages but prettier was highlighting my vscode interface with errors - I dont need this as I have autofix on save which will fix everything without me even knowing that there were few unnecessary tabs. this was just annoying to see errors everywhere

Answer (score 0):

So I had both `eslint-plugin-prettier` and `eslint-config-prettier` on my package.json as devdependencies. I removed the eslint-config-prettier and it seemed to work for me.

```js
//.eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['@react-native', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react-native/no-inline-styles': 'off',
  },
};
```