# How to ignore specific rule(s) with prettier?

Tags: javascript, prettier

Is there a way to not `format` `write` or `check` specific rules with prettier?

For example I don't care if there is semicolon or not in my code, I want to check for other rules than that.

```json
"prettier": {
  "useTabs": true,
  "tabWidth": 4,
}
```

Comment: Use a [prettier rc file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)?

Comment: @AlexanderNied i use `package.json` which is the same and it only specifies how rules apply, if it set to `"semi": false` it will look for semicolons and remove them, and if it set to `"semi": true` it will look for *missing* semicolons and add them, there is no way i found to ignore if there is or isnt a semicolon.

Comment: In [this Prettier issue from 2018](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5007) they gave a pretty direct "this is not possible" response.  Unless there has been a change in their approach since then it would appear that this is, unfortunately, not possible. (Unless I am still misunderstanding the issue).

Answer (score -8, accepted):

As answered by one of the contributors [Prettier doesn't have rules and will never have](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9171#issuecomment-689596261)

Comment: This is a technicality, as its obvious the OP means options instead of rules, although they refer in their docs to these as options - this is crystal clear - however answer is not helpful at all

Comment: Clearly semantics. Obviously there are rules; they just call them options.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no.

It has been stated that it will never provide the ability to ignore certain "rules" or "options".

https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9171
(Thanks to @ColdHands for the reference).

This is because the tool itself is unashamedly *opinionated*: https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html