# How to remove Prettier errors from blocking page render

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

Can't view page because of error message:

[image]

Negligible prettier errors are blocking the page itself, how do i disable this feature?
Current setup:

.prettierrc

```
{
  "printWidth": 120,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 2018,
  "sourceType": "module",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  }
},
"extends": [
  "airbnb-base",
  "plugin:prettier/recommended",
  "prettier/react"
],
"env": {
  "es6": true, 
  "browser": true
},
"plugins": [
  "prettier"
],
"rules": {
  "prettier/prettier": ["error", {
    "endOfLine": "auto"
  }]
}
}
```

Comment: May be you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424718/how-can-i-disable-the-error-prettier-prettier-on-eslint), which will disable the prettier

Answer (score 0):

I would sugggest you to configure your environment to formatOnSave, then your prettier errors would be fixed right away. you don't have to bother to remove some silly typing errors while maintaining your code quality. if you use vscode you can install `eslint` extension and configure at your `.vscode` workspace settings, or globally:

```
{
  "eslint.validate": [ "javascript", "html"],

  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [".js", "html"]
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
  }
}
```